# MySQL Workbench Dark Theme

Tags: themes, mysql-workbench

How can I change MySQL Workbench settings so that it uses a dark theme?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

MySQL Workbench's themes are a collection of colors for certain main parts of the application. It is planned to allow customizing them in a later version. In order to get a dark theme as one of the templates please file a feature request at http://bugs.mysql.com. But keep in mind, not every UI element is colored according to the Workbench theme, e.g. text boxes still stay white as they use the Windows standard colors.

Comment: This may do. I am after changing the most of the white background on the workspace. Thanks.

Comment: There's no dark theme, but I added a high contrast theme. Set your system to dark to make most of the windows using a dark background.

Answer (score 110):

Here's how to change MySQL Workbench's colors (INCLUDING THE BACKGROUND COLOR).

Open the XML file called `code_editor.xml` located in the data folder of the MySQL Workbench's installation directory (usually `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\data`). Here you'll find a lot of styling for different code elements, but there are some missing.

MySQL Workbench uses scintilla as the code editor, and scintilla defines a few more styles that you can use in the `code_editor.xml` file. The one that is used for the **background color is style id 32**.

Here's the complete list for MySQL (scintilla has thousands of styles for many languages) with my configuration:

```html
<style id= "0" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DEFAULT                  -->
<style id= "1" fore-color="#999999" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT                  -->
<style id= "2" fore-color="#999999" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE              -->
<style id= "3" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE                 -->
<style id= "4" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE           -->
<style id= "5" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE      -->
<style id= "6" fore-color="#FF8080" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER                   -->
<style id= "7" fore-color="#7AAAD7" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD             -->
<style id= "8" fore-color="#7AAAD7" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD                  -->
<style id= "9" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DATABASEOBJECT           -->
<style id="10" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD         -->
<style id="11" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_STRING                   -->
<style id="12" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING                 -->
<style id="13" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING                 -->
<style id="14" fore-color="#FFBB80" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR                 -->
<style id="15" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION                 -->
<style id="16" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER               -->
<style id="17" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER         -->
<style id="18" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1                    -->
<style id="19" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER2                    -->
<style id="20" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER3                    -->
<style id="21" fore-color="#FFBB80" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_HIDDENCOMMAND            -->
<style id="22" fore-color="#909090" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER              -->

<!-- These two are for scintilla globally. -->
<style id="32" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- STYLE_DEFAULT                      THIS IS THE ONE FOR THE BACKGROUND!!!!! -->
<style id="33" fore-color="#2A2A2A" back-color="#DDDDDD" bold="No" />   <!-- STYLE_LINENUMBER                   -->

<!-- All styles again in their variant in a hidden command (with a 0x40 offset). -->
<style id="65" fore-color="#999999" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT                  -->
<style id="66" fore-color="#999999" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE              -->
<style id="67" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE                 -->
<style id="68" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE           -->
<style id="69" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE      -->
<style id="70" fore-color="#FF8080" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER                   -->
<style id="71" fore-color="#7AAAD7" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD             -->
<style id="72" fore-color="#7AAAD7" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD                  -->
<style id="73" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DATABASEOBJECT           -->
<style id="74" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD         -->
<style id="75" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_STRING                   -->
<style id="76" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING                 -->
<style id="77" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING                 -->
<style id="78" fore-color="#FFBB80" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR                 -->
<style id="79" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION                 -->
<style id="80" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER               -->
<style id="81" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER         -->
<style id="82" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1                    -->
<style id="83" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER2                    -->
<style id="84" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER3                    -->
<style id="85" fore-color="#FFBB80" back-color="#909090" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_HIDDENCOMMAND            -->
<style id="86" fore-color="#AAAAAA" back-color="#909090" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER              -->
```

Comment: wow - that totally worked.  even for workbench 6.2.  now if I could only "fix" the rest of the chrome and the "navigator" side bar.   but this solution does wonders for my eyes.  thanks a ton!!!

Comment: Didn't work for me on 6.3!
did you just add it at the end (before closing tags ofcourse, same level as the rest of styles)

Comment: For those having trouble, you must paste these styles in the `<language name="SCLEX_MYSQL">` node, not at the end of the file.

Comment: These don't seem to exist in 6.3.7. Did they remove this ability?

Comment: For Mac users, the code_editor.xml file is in `MBP HD/ Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/data/`

Comment: Changing "style id 32" does not work in 6.3 - no effect, consider changing the answer to reflect this.

    <style id="32" fore-color="#FFFFFF" back-color="#000000" 
    
    bold="No" />   <!-- STYLE_DEFAULT                      THIS IS THE ONE FOR THE 
    
    BACKGROUND!!!!! -->

Comment: Awesome, works for me on Mac and Workbench 6.3 .  I have floaters in my both eyes and white backgrounds are such a hell for me. You made my day :)

Comment: is there anyway to change the mouse pointer and text cursor to white? i've changed the background to dark but now its difficult to see the pointer on OSX

Comment: It works to replace the styles in the node mentioned above (SCLEX_MYSQL) on 6.3 on Ubuntu. The file location is at: 
`/usr/share/mysql-workbench/data/code_editor.xml` 

That edits the main editor. Other sub-windows are still white and there is a lot more to edit to make it a nice "dark" theme. I look forward to someone taking the time to making that nice :-)

Comment: @Gaston can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @Steve please let us know if you found a way to make the cursor color in contrast with the dark bg.

Comment: Worked for me, made my day! Version 8.0.11

Comment: this only changes the text editor for me...is there any way to change the IDE panels and toolbars to a dark theme as well?

Comment: This is just amazing! Any idea how to change the color of the "Management" box?
There's an OSX dark mode now, but it's not totally right. The text in those menus are black on grey. 
And thanks for this! It's great!

Comment: This successfully changes the font color for me, but the editor background color is still white. Anyone else experience this, or have an idea of the solution? Thanks for this!

Comment: @jtate For Ubuntu 18.04 - Change the shell theme to dark

Comment: How to change the cursor color to white, with dark background the cursor is almost invisible.

Comment: @Sab how do you change the shell theme?

Comment: @Kalle use gnome tweak tool. Install dark theme and apply. My choice of theme is pop which is bundled with different variants light, normal, dark. I chose dark theme.

Comment: Didn't work for me in v8.0.16 on Windows. I replaced the styles in the tag `<language name="SCLEX_MYSQL">` And tried all themes with no luck

Comment: @Madacol check this answer https://superuser.com/a/1477257 I've tested it on Windows 10 x64 with 8.0.17 and it works great.

Comment: Wait so do you just paset these into the <language name="SCLEX_MYSQL "paste here"?>. You paste into that < >? Because I did that and it made no difference when I reopened Workbench. Is there somewhere else within the Workbench GUI that I need to go to see and select a theme? Besides under "Edit->Preferences-> Fonts & Colors  @MissRaphie

Comment: @Madacol I am on Windows 10 Workbench 8.0, can't get this to work. Wait so do you just paset these into the <language name="SCLEX_MYSQL "paste here"?>. You paste into that < >? Because I did that and it made no difference when I reopened Workbench. Is there somewhere else within the Workbench GUI that I need to go to see and select a theme? Besides under "Edit->Preferences-> Fonts & Colors What am I missing here

Comment: Okay I got it but mine has white background whenever I type. My text is surround by white instead of being dark with text @Gaston Martinez

Comment: @edo101 look at Adam Mańkowski comment. This works for v8.0+ versions.

Comment: This answer may be helpful, but year is 2021 and still there is no any complete dark theme in MySQL workbench(!) :(

Answer (score 53):

You can disable MySQL WorkBench dark-mode using default - run below command on your terminal/console.

```
defaults write com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool yes
```

Comment: I was looking how to disable dark mode only for Mysql Workbench and couldn't find it anywhere but here. I ran this and it worked. Thanks!.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpful!

Comment: btw, the same cmd with `-bool no` turns back theme on again !

Comment: Yes, thanks! This is what I was looking for. Not sure who came up with the color themes for MySQL, but they really need to fix that.

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful. The dark theme makes everything unreadable and way too contrasty.

Comment: I will not upvote this because it's off topic with the question, but I do appreciate it solved my problem. Thanks. :D

Comment: Thank you so much. I finding to disable dark mode for days in my mac default dark theme. Now, solved.

Comment: It's working on MacBook, thanks !

Comment: Can someone please help and tell me how to do this in Ubuntu cause to above command is now working in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 42):

**MySQL Workbench 8.0 Update**

Based on Gunther's answer, it seems like in `code_editor.xml` they're planning to enable a dark mode at some point down the road. What was once `fore-color` has now been split into `fore-color-light` and `fore-color-dark`. Likewise with `back-color`.

Here's how to get a dark *editor* (not whole application theme) based on the Monokai colours provided graciously by elMestre:

```xml
<!-- 
dark-gray:         #282828;
brown-gray:        #49483E;
gray:              #888888;
light-gray:        #CCCCCC;
ghost-white:       #F8F8F0;
light-ghost-white: #F8F8F2;
yellow:            #E6DB74;
blue:              #66D9EF;
pink:              #F92672;
purple:            #AE81FF;
brown:             #75715E;
orange:            #FD971F;
light-orange:      #FFD569;
green:             #A6E22E;
sea-green:         #529B2F; 
-->

<style id="32" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#DDDDDD" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- STYLE_DEFAULT       !BACKGROUND!   -->
<style id="33" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#DDDDDD" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- STYLE_LINENUMBER                   -->
<style id= "0" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#DDDDDD" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DEFAULT                  -->

<style id= "1" fore-color-light="#999999" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#999999" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT                  -->
<style id= "2" fore-color-light="#999999" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#999999" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE              -->
<style id= "3" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#DDDDDD" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE                 -->
<style id= "4" fore-color-light="#66D9EF" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#66D9EF" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE           -->
<style id= "5" fore-color-light="#66D9EF" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#66D9EF" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE      -->
<style id= "6" fore-color-light="#AE81FF" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#AE81FF" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER                   -->
<style id= "7" fore-color-light="#F92672" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#F92672" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD             -->
<style id= "8" fore-color-light="#F92672" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#F92672" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD                  -->
<style id= "9" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#9B859D" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DATABASEOBJECT           -->
<style id="10" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#DDDDDD" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD         -->
<style id="11" fore-color-light="#E6DB74" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#E6DB74" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_STRING                   -->
<style id="12" fore-color-light="#E6DB74" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#E6DB74" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING                 -->
<style id="13" fore-color-light="#E6DB74" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#E6DB74" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING                 -->
<style id="14" fore-color-light="#F92672" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#F92672" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR                 -->
<style id="15" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#9B859D" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION                 -->
<style id="16" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#DDDDDD" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER               -->
<style id="17" fore-color-light="#E6DB74" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#E6DB74" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER         -->
<style id="18" fore-color-light="#529B2F" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#529B2F" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1                    -->
<style id="19" fore-color-light="#529B2F" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#529B2F" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER2                    -->
<style id="20" fore-color-light="#529B2F" back-color-light="#282828" fore-color-dark="#529B2F" back-color-dark="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER3                    -->
<style id="21" fore-color-light="#66D9EF" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#66D9EF" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_HIDDENCOMMAND            -->
<style id="22" fore-color-light="#909090" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#909090" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER              -->
<!-- All styles again in their variant in a hidden command -->
<style id="65" fore-color-light="#999999" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#999999" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT                  -->
<style id="66" fore-color-light="#999999" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#999999" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE              -->
<style id="67" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#DDDDDD" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE                 -->
<style id="68" fore-color-light="#66D9EF" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#66D9EF" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE           -->
<style id="69" fore-color-light="#66D9EF" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#66D9EF" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE      -->
<style id="70" fore-color-light="#AE81FF" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#AE81FF" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER                   -->
<style id="71" fore-color-light="#F92672" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#F92672" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD             -->
<style id="72" fore-color-light="#F92672" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#F92672" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD                  -->
<style id="73" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#9B859D" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DATABASEOBJECT           -->
<style id="74" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#DDDDDD" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD         -->
<style id="75" fore-color-light="#E6DB74" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#E6DB74" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_STRING                   -->
<style id="76" fore-color-light="#E6DB74" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#E6DB74" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING                 -->
<style id="77" fore-color-light="#E6DB74" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#E6DB74" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING                 -->
<style id="78" fore-color-light="#F92672" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#F92672" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR                 -->
<style id="79" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#9B859D" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION                 -->
<style id="80" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#DDDDDD" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER               -->
<style id="81" fore-color-light="#E6DB74" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#E6DB74" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER         -->
<style id="82" fore-color-light="#529B2F" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#529B2F" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1                    -->
<style id="83" fore-color-light="#529B2F" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#529B2F" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER2                    -->
<style id="84" fore-color-light="#529B2F" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#529B2F" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER3                    -->
<style id="85" fore-color-light="#66D9EF" back-color-light="#888888" fore-color-dark="#66D9EF" back-color-dark="#888888" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_HIDDENCOMMAND            -->
<style id="86" fore-color-light="#AAAAAA" back-color-light="#888888" fore-color-dark="#AAAAAA" back-color-dark="#888888" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER              -->
```

Remember to paste all these styles inside of the `<language name="SCLEX_MYSQL">` tag in `data > code_editor.xml`.

[image]

Comment: Wait so do you just paset these into the <language name="SCLEX_MYSQL "paste here"?>. You paste into that < >? Because I did that and it made no difference when I reopened Workbench. Is there somewhere else within the Workbench GUI that I need to go to see and select a theme? Besides under "Edit->Preferences-> Fonts & Colors

Comment: Wait so do you just paset these into the <language name="SCLEX_MYSQL "paste here"?>. You paste into that < >? Because I did that and it made no difference when I reopened Workbench. Is there somewhere else within the Workbench GUI that I need to go to see and select a theme? Besides under "Edit->Preferences-> Fonts & Colors   @VSingh

Comment: Okay I got it but mine has white background whenever I type. My text is surround by white instead of being dark with text.

Comment: I was going to update my post for the version, but you already did and works perfectly.

Thanks man.

Comment: @VSingh - thnx a Ton!!! that was a cool hack.
After editing the xml file, my sql editor window has gone dark.

Comment: I was having the same issue as @edo101 and figured it out. Paste the the styles at the bottom of the tag, not at the beginning because other stuff in there overwrites the styles.

Answer (score 26):

**Edit:** Advise: This answer is old and a better solution can be found in this same page. This answer referred to MySQL Workbench 6.3 and is outdated. If you are using a new version (8.0 as today) look for @VSingh comment in this very page.

---

**Original answer:**

Just a copy of Gaston's answer, but with **Monokai** theme colors.

```xml
<!-- 
    dark-gray:         #282828;
    brown-gray:        #49483E;
    gray:              #888888;
    light-gray:        #CCCCCC;
    ghost-white:       #F8F8F0;
    light-ghost-white: #F8F8F2;
    yellow:            #E6DB74;
    blue:              #66D9EF;
    pink:              #F92672;
    purple:            #AE81FF;
    brown:             #75715E;
    orange:            #FD971F;
    light-orange:      #FFD569;
    green:             #A6E22E;
    sea-green:         #529B2F; 
-->
<style id="32" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- STYLE_DEFAULT       !BACKGROUND!   -->
<style id="33" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- STYLE_LINENUMBER                   -->
<style id= "0" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DEFAULT                  -->
<style id= "1" fore-color="#999999" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT                  -->
<style id= "2" fore-color="#999999" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE              -->
<style id= "3" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE                 -->
<style id= "4" fore-color="#66D9EF" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE           -->
<style id= "5" fore-color="#66D9EF" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE      -->
<style id= "6" fore-color="#AE81FF" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER                   -->
<style id= "7" fore-color="#F92672" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD             -->
<style id= "8" fore-color="#F92672" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD                  -->
<style id= "9" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DATABASEOBJECT           -->
<style id="10" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD         -->
<style id="11" fore-color="#E6DB74" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_STRING                   -->
<style id="12" fore-color="#E6DB74" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING                 -->
<style id="13" fore-color="#E6DB74" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING                 -->
<style id="14" fore-color="#F92672" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR                 -->
<style id="15" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION                 -->
<style id="16" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER               -->
<style id="17" fore-color="#E6DB74" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER         -->
<style id="18" fore-color="#529B2F" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1                    -->
<style id="19" fore-color="#529B2F" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER2                    -->
<style id="20" fore-color="#529B2F" back-color="#282828" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER3                    -->
<style id="21" fore-color="#66D9EF" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_HIDDENCOMMAND            -->
<style id="22" fore-color="#909090" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER              -->
<!-- All styles again in their variant in a hidden command -->
<style id="65" fore-color="#999999" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT                  -->
<style id="66" fore-color="#999999" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE              -->
<style id="67" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE                 -->
<style id="68" fore-color="#66D9EF" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE           -->
<style id="69" fore-color="#66D9EF" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE      -->
<style id="70" fore-color="#AE81FF" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER                   -->
<style id="71" fore-color="#F92672" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD             -->
<style id="72" fore-color="#F92672" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD                  -->
<style id="73" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DATABASEOBJECT           -->
<style id="74" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD         -->
<style id="75" fore-color="#E6DB74" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_STRING                   -->
<style id="76" fore-color="#E6DB74" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING                 -->
<style id="77" fore-color="#E6DB74" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING                 -->
<style id="78" fore-color="#F92672" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR                 -->
<style id="79" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION                 -->
<style id="80" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER               -->
<style id="81" fore-color="#E6DB74" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER         -->
<style id="82" fore-color="#529B2F" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1                    -->
<style id="83" fore-color="#529B2F" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER2                    -->
<style id="84" fore-color="#529B2F" back-color="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER3                    -->
<style id="85" fore-color="#66D9EF" back-color="#888888" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_HIDDENCOMMAND            -->
<style id="86" fore-color="#AAAAAA" back-color="#888888" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER              -->
```

Comment: Wait so do you just paset these into the <language name="SCLEX_MYSQL "paste here"?>. You paste into that <  >? Because I did that and it made no difference when I reopened Workbench. Is there somewhere else within the Workbench GUI that I need to go to see and select a theme? Besides under "Edit->Preferences-> Fonts & Colors

Comment: Wait so do you just paset these into the <language name="SCLEX_MYSQL "paste here"?>. You paste into that < >? Because I did that and it made no difference when I reopened Workbench. Is there somewhere else within the Workbench GUI that I need to go to see and select a theme? Besides under "Edit->Preferences-> Fonts & Colors  What am I missing here @elMestre

Comment: Okay I got it but mine has white background whenever I type. My text is surround by white instead of being dark with text @elMestre

Comment: Please, this was for version 6.3. Nowadays use @VSingh answer

Answer (score 25):

### For disabling dark mode in MySQL Workbench on macOS

Open terminal and use the following command:

```
defaults write com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool yes
```

---

### For enabling dark mode in MySQL Workbench on macOS

Open terminal and use the following command:

```
defaults write com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool no
```

Comment: Best answer. Simple and fast.

Comment: This works for the main editor window. However, if you right click on a resultset cell and choose 'open value in editor', both the font and the bg become black and you end up not being able to read anything.

Answer (score 16):

FYI Dark theme is now in the Dev Version of `MySQL Workbench`

Update: From what I can tell it is Natively built into `MySQL Workbench 8.0.15` for `MAC OS X`

The package I downloaded was  `mysql-workbench-community-8.0.15-macos-x86_64.dmg`

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/
[image]

Comment: How to enable? Where is the Setting?

Comment: Ahhh, but not for windows :(

Comment: It requires switching to the MacOS system-wide dark mode. There doesn't seem to be a way to toggle the MySQL Workbench dark mode independently.

Comment: Mac: `System Preferences > General > Appearance`

Comment: This answer really got my hopes up. 30 mins of reinstalling and fiddling with the preferences, it's only then that I read the comments about it being MacOS only. 2 years on and still no dark theme on Windows :(

Comment: Found an alternative - HeidiSQL (different editor). Seems to do the same and it has a 'charcoal' theme which is pretty much an exact match for the standard dark theme in PHPStorm. Only drawback is that the spacing is slightly different but I expect it's just a matter of getting used to it.

Comment: Another alternative is Dbeaver that also supplies a Dark Theme if needed.

Answer (score 9):

For Ubuntu Users, the `code_editor.xml` is in

`/usr/share/mysql-workbench/data`

edit as you need, In Ubuntu which is a must need, some default used colours lacks contrast and it is unable to read,
For a quick workaround you can also use this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1111198/1172766).

Visit [this repo](https://github.com/mleandrojr/mysql-workbench-dark-theme) to get the full XML file.

Comment: The recommended repo xml file solved it for me (Ubuntu 20.04). My eyes thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The hack by VSingh is better than nothing.

However Visual Studio Code has a passable mySQL addon by cweijan and it DOES support dark themes (several actually).  It pretty much does everything you could need, just a bit of a learning curve to figure out the new interface.  It also supports several other database engines I use, so it's fast becoming my hole in one.

I'm tired of getting arc eyes every time I have to run a query, it gives me a headache.  They implemented it for Mac, how long does it take to do the same for Windows?

I will be using VS Code for as much as possible from now on, maybe I will look at this later when the developers wake up.

Answer (score 3):

For a more straight forward Windows answer. Just replace the code_editor.xml file with the one here: https://github.com/mleandrojr/mysql-workbench-dark-theme. It's not perfect but the query window is dark now.

Comment: Tested this on 8.0.32, doesn't work for windows.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting Yoga...

> For Mac users, the code_editor.xml file is in MBP HD/ Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/data/

I just discovered by dumbfounded experimentation (i.e. first thing I tried, worked) that if I copy **that** file to...

/Users/your.username/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench/code_editor.xml

...and then edit it **there**, it does indeed override. Just worked perfectly for me on Mac OS X Sierra and MySQL Workbench 6.3.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed something is missing here for linux users, if you use Snap to install workbench the installation directory would be different from what mentioned above. Something like:

> ~/snap/mysql-workbench-community/10/.mysql/workbench

or absolute location:

```
/home/YOURUSERNAME/snap/mysql-workbench-community/10/.mysql/workbench
```

Answer (score 1):

### On Ubuntu:

#### Theme Dracula MySQL Workbench

[Theme Dracula MySQL Workbench](https://draculatheme.com/mysql-workbench)

> [image: Theme Dracula MySQL Workbench]

- `git clone https://github.com/dracula/mysql-workbench.git`

1. Copy the code from the `copy.xml` file
2. Go to `/usr/share/mysql-workbench/data`
3. Open `code_editor.xml`
4. Paste the code you've selected before inside the tag `<language name="SCLEX_MYSQL">`, replacing all styles in that tag
5. Open your MySQL Workbench and be happy!

Answer (score 0):

For users of snap on Linux, a partial solution, see figure.
Based on @bl3ssedc0de answer: ([read this first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325408/mysql-workbench-dark-theme#73285816)!)

```bash
# Create the folder snap-tests/mysql-workbench in your home folder, 
# then extract the original snap to that folder
sudo unsquashfs -d /home/USERNAME/snap-tests/mysql-workbench/ /var/lib/snapd/snaps/mysql-workbench-community_12.snap 

# Copy the contents of the downloaded copy.xml file to clipboard, (see @bl3ssedc0de !) (requires xclip)
xclip -sel c < path_to_repo_copy/mysql-workbench/copy.xml 
# to the file: (see @bl3ssedc0de !)
sudo gnome-text-editor /home/USERNAME/snap-tests/mysql-workbench/usr/share/mysql-workbench/data/code_editor.xml 

# Replace original snap
sudo snap try /home/USERNAME/snap-tests/mysql-workbench
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the @Gaston Martinez's answer, you can use this modified XML snippet to change the colors on the editor section, as you can see, this code meets the original bold format of some elements like keywords, it also has cool colors on comments, strings and numbers. In this code you might see that I have changed *fore-color* by *fore-color-light* and *back-color* by *back-color-light*, because those options were not recognized by Workbench.

**Instructions**

1. Navigate to this path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\data.
2. There, you will find a file named *code_editor.xml*, it's a good idea to copy the file for having a backup.
3. Open the file as an editor and look for the tag *<language name="SCLEX_MYSQL">*, within this tag you will copy the **XML colors code**, you can copy that in the end, e.g.

   <language name="SCLEX_MYSQL">

           Original content

           . . .

           . . .

           . . .

           Here in the end you can copy the **XML colors code**

   </language name="SCLEX_MYSQL">
4. Save the file and open MySQL Workbech :)

**XML colors code:**

```xml
<style id= "0" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DEFAULT                  -->
<style id= "1" fore-color-light="#BAF505" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT                  -->
<style id= "2" fore-color-light="#BAF505" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE              -->
<style id= "3" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE                 -->
<style id= "4" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE           -->
<style id= "5" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE      -->
<style id= "6" fore-color-light="#FFB430" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER                   -->
<style id= "7" fore-color-light="#7AAAD7" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="Yes" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD             -->
<style id= "8" fore-color-light="#7AAAD7" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="Yes" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD                  -->
<style id= "9" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DATABASEOBJECT           -->
<style id="10" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD         -->
<style id="11" fore-color-light="#FC65F0" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_STRING                   -->
<style id="12" fore-color-light="#FC65F0" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING                 -->
<style id="13" fore-color-light="#FC65F0" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING                 -->
<style id="14" fore-color-light="#FFBB80" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR                 -->
<style id="15" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION                 -->
<style id="16" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER               -->
<style id="17" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER         -->
<style id="18" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="Yes" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1                    -->
<style id="19" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER2                    -->
<style id="20" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER3                    -->
<style id="21" fore-color-light="#FFBB80" back-color-light="#707070" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_HIDDENCOMMAND            -->
<style id="22" fore-color-light="#909090" back-color-light="#707070" bold="Yes" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER              -->
<style id="32" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" fore-color-dark="#DDDDDD" back-color-dark="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- STYLE_DEFAULT                      THIS IS THE ONE FOR THE BACKGROUND!!!!! -->
<style id="33" fore-color-light="#2A2A2A" back-color-light="#DDDDDD" fore-color-dark="#DDDDDD" back-color-dark="#2A2A2A" bold="Yes" />   <!-- STYLE_LINENUMBER                   -->
<style id="65" fore-color-light="#BAF505" back-color-light="#707070" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT                  -->
<style id="66" fore-color-light="#BAF505" back-color-light="#707070" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE              -->
<style id="67" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#707070" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE                 -->
<style id="68" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#707070" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE           -->
<style id="69" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#707070" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE      -->
<style id="70" fore-color-light="#FFB430" back-color-light="#707070" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER                   -->
<style id="71" fore-color-light="#7AAAD7" back-color-light="#707070" bold="Yes" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD             -->
<style id="72" fore-color-light="#7AAAD7" back-color-light="#707070" bold="Yes" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD                  -->
<style id="73" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#707070" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DATABASEOBJECT           -->
<style id="74" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#707070" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD         -->
<style id="75" fore-color-light="#FC65F0" back-color-light="#707070" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_STRING                   -->
<style id="76" fore-color-light="#FC65F0" back-color-light="#707070" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING                 -->
<style id="77" fore-color-light="#FC65F0" back-color-light="#707070" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING                 -->
<style id="78" fore-color-light="#FFBB80" back-color-light="#707070" bold="Yes" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR                 -->
<style id="79" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#707070" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION                 -->
<style id="80" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#707070" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER               -->
<style id="81" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#707070" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER         -->
<style id="82" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#707070" bold="Yes" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1                    -->
<style id="83" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#707070" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER2                    -->
<style id="84" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#707070" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER3                    -->
<style id="85" fore-color-light="#FFBB80" back-color-light="#909090" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_HIDDENCOMMAND            -->
<style id="86" fore-color-light="#AAAAAA" back-color-light="#909090" bold="Yes" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER              -->
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Go to C:\Program Files\MySQL
2. Now go to 'mysql workbench' folder and then go to 'data' folder.
3. Open code_editor.xml
4. Paste the code given below inside the tag `<language name="SCLEX_MYSQL">`, replacing all styles in that tag and save the file.
5. Open your MySQL Workbench and have fun.

```xml
    <!-- 
dark-gray:         #282a36;
brown-gray:        #49483E;
gray:              #888888;
light-gray:        #CCCCCC;
ghost-white:       #F8F8F0;
light-ghost-white: #F8F8F2;
yellow:            #f1fa8c;
blue:              #8be9fd;
pink:              #ff79c6;
purple:            #bd93f9;
brown:             #75715E;
orange:            #FD971F;
light-orange:      #ffb86c;
green:             #50fa7b;
sea-green:         #529B2F; 
-->

<style id="32" fore-color-light="#f8f8f2" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#f8f8f2" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- STYLE_DEFAULT       !BACKGROUND!   -->
<style id="33" fore-color-light="#f8f8f2" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#f8f8f2" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- STYLE_LINENUMBER                   -->
<style id= "0" fore-color-light="#f8f8f2" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#f8f8f2" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DEFAULT                  -->

<style id= "1" fore-color-light="#6272a4" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#6272a4" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT                  -->
<style id= "2" fore-color-light="#6272a4" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#6272a4" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE              -->
<style id= "3" fore-color-light="#f8f8f2" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#f8f8f2" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE                 -->
<style id= "4" fore-color-light="#8be9fd" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#8be9fd" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE           -->
<style id= "5" fore-color-light="#8be9fd" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#8be9fd" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE      -->
<style id= "6" fore-color-light="#bd93f9" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#bd93f9" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER                   -->
<style id= "7" fore-color-light="#ff79c6" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#ff79c6" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD             -->
<style id= "8" fore-color-light="#ff79c6" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#ff79c6" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD                  -->
<style id= "9" fore-color-light="#50fa7b" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#50fa7b" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DATABASEOBJECT           -->
<style id="10" fore-color-light="#f8f8f2" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#f8f8f2" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD         -->
<style id="11" fore-color-light="#f1fa8c" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#f1fa8c" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_STRING                   -->
<style id="12" fore-color-light="#f1fa8c" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#f1fa8c" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING                 -->
<style id="13" fore-color-light="#f1fa8c" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#f1fa8c" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING                 -->
<style id="14" fore-color-light="#ff79c6" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#ff79c6" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR                 -->
<style id="15" fore-color-light="#50fa7b" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#50fa7b" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION                 -->
<style id="16" fore-color-light="#f8f8f2" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#f8f8f2" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER               -->
<style id="17" fore-color-light="#f1fa8c" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#f1fa8c" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER         -->
<style id="18" fore-color-light="#529B2F" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#529B2F" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1                    -->
<style id="19" fore-color-light="#529B2F" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#529B2F" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER2                    -->
<style id="20" fore-color-light="#529B2F" back-color-light="#282a36" fore-color-dark="#529B2F" back-color-dark="#282a36" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER3                    -->
<style id="21" fore-color-light="#8be9fd" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#8be9fd" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_HIDDENCOMMAND            -->
<style id="22" fore-color-light="#909090" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#909090" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER              -->
<!-- All styles again in their variant in a hidden command -->
<style id="65" fore-color-light="#6272a4" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#6272a4" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT                  -->
<style id="66" fore-color-light="#6272a4" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#6272a4" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE              -->
<style id="67" fore-color-light="#f8f8f2" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#f8f8f2" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE                 -->
<style id="68" fore-color-light="#8be9fd" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#8be9fd" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE           -->
<style id="69" fore-color-light="#8be9fd" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#8be9fd" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE      -->
<style id="70" fore-color-light="#bd93f9" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#bd93f9" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER                   -->
<style id="71" fore-color-light="#ff79c6" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#ff79c6" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD             -->
<style id="72" fore-color-light="#ff79c6" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#ff79c6" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD                  -->
<style id="73" fore-color-light="#50fa7b" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#50fa7b" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DATABASEOBJECT           -->
<style id="74" fore-color-light="#f8f8f2" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#f8f8f2" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD         -->
<style id="75" fore-color-light="#f1fa8c" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#f1fa8c" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_STRING                   -->
<style id="76" fore-color-light="#f1fa8c" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#f1fa8c" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING                 -->
<style id="77" fore-color-light="#f1fa8c" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#f1fa8c" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING                 -->
<style id="78" fore-color-light="#ff79c6" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#ff79c6" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR                 -->
<style id="79" fore-color-light="#50fa7b" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#50fa7b" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION                 -->
<style id="80" fore-color-light="#f8f8f2" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#f8f8f2" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER               -->
<style id="81" fore-color-light="#f1fa8c" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#f1fa8c" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER         -->
<style id="82" fore-color-light="#529B2F" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#529B2F" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1                    -->
<style id="83" fore-color-light="#529B2F" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#529B2F" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER2                    -->
<style id="84" fore-color-light="#529B2F" back-color-light="#49483E" fore-color-dark="#529B2F" back-color-dark="#49483E" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER3                    -->
<style id="85" fore-color-light="#8be9fd" back-color-light="#888888" fore-color-dark="#8be9fd" back-color-dark="#888888" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_HIDDENCOMMAND            -->
<style id="86" fore-color-light="#AAAAAA" back-color-light="#888888" fore-color-dark="#AAAAAA" back-color-dark="#888888" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER              -->
```

Comment: Rahul charan, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: The answer has been edited.