# Can't update theme on MySQL Workbench for Mac

Tags: mysql, themes, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench on Mac to write queries and I can't find a way to change the GUI theme. It looks from the online resources that are available like users can usually fix this by going to Preferences and going to Preferences and selecting "Fonts & Colours". This is what it usually looks like, apparently:

[Preferences page according to online resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mun3.png)

However, when I go to my preferences, this section just appears as "Fonts" and no option to change theme is provided:

[Preferences page on Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr8Ms.png)

Is this because I'm on Mac? And is there another way to change to a darker theme? I've been able to last for a while but the white is murder on my eyes.

Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Workbench Dark Theme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325408/mysql-workbench-dark-theme)

Comment: If you can't get it working and want to try an alternative, I recommend Sequel Pro. It's free and (IMO) better than MySQL Workbench. You can configure the query editor colours to your hearts content too :)

Comment: I don't think so @Don'tPanic - I looked into that post and they didn't mention  being unable to access their themes. I also can't find the xml file one of the answers recommended checking.

Comment: @smilin_stan Great, thank you! I'll definitely take a look.

Comment: I did not initially realize that you could not even see the themes option. I assume that probably is a Mac thing. For what it's worth, I am using it on Windows, and I can change the theme, but there are only a couple of themes to choose from and they all have white backgrounds.

Comment: MySQL Workbench also honours the Windows theme, including dark backgrounds, hi-contrast etc. Just set the theme to OS native and change the OS'es theme settings.

Comment: @MikeLischke I did not realize that! I will definitely experiment with that. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme settings in MySQL Workbench are for Windows only, hence this setting is not visible in OSX or Linux. The dark theme in OSX is rather new and doesn't usually affect applications, so there is no meaning in adding support for that in MySQL Workbench. Of course the menu bar is still dark, also when WB is the active application (if set to that).

The other color settings (like those you can change via the xml or any other you see in the preferences) are used to change syntax highlighting colors and modeling colors.

Comment: you can exclude the dark mode only for MySQLWorkbench by https://stackoverflow.com/a/53861198/8074791

Answer (score 33):

I was trying to remove dark mode from MySQL Workbench version 8.0.15 and the following command in the Terminal did the trick (Running MacOS Mojave 10.14.5):

```
defaults write com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool yes
```

You can try changing the bool condition to 'no' to go back to dark mode.

I referenced this thread : https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92902 and the comment from Jonas Trollvik.

Comment: this is the key!!! OMG thank you so much. The dark theme on mac is broke and white letters on white background messes things up, but this fixes. I recommend existing MySQL workbench beforehand of course.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to system preferences
In General>appearance > Light
It will reflect

Answer (score -3):

Seems the dark theme has now been considered for the latest version, 8.0.13, but think i'll be rolling back as the it's terrible.

[MySQL Workbench 8.0.13 Mac - Dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmUPh.png)

Comment: instead of your opinion, the questioner can use your help to change the theme they wanted