# MySQL Workbench: Unable to see text

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My installation of MySQL Workbench is rather unusable because of the font/background colours. Initially I assumed that this was due to the Light/Dark theme on Mac OSX Mojave, but I have switched between both and it still remains the same. The problem has only started since I upgraded to Mac OSX Mojave. Is there anything I can do to make things more visible?

[image: Worbench Screenshot]

Edit: My currently selected theme is the 'Light Theme'

[image: Light Theme]

Comment: That obviously is **not** the dark mode :-D

Comment: Oh, how embarrassing!

Comment: Uh, it's embarrasing that I confused things here. The screenshot shows your box is in dark mode, even if the drop down says "Light (still)" and I meant to say: this is obviously **not** the light mode. You don't switch that in the Desktop & Screen Saver section but in the Common section, under Appearance.

Comment: Thanks, I switched it to the light mode under preferences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL Workbench 8.0.13 doesn't support the new dark mode of macOS Mojave yet. This will come with a future release. Until then keep using the light mode if the use of MySQL Workbench (and other software which still needs to be updated) is essential for you.

**Update**

Starting with MySQL Workbench 8.0.14 the new dark mode is fully supported.

Comment: Thank you - I do have the Light Theme selected. Have also performed the obligatory restarts to the system to ensure the effects take place fully, so as of now, my browsers and other applications have transitioned to the Light theme, but not Workbench.

Comment: I'm using 8.0.15 and still have the problem of black text on a black background. If it was fixed in 8.0.14, it's back in 8.0.15. I'm using Mac OS 10.14.3 with the dark mode.

Comment: @MikeLischke Just saw someone else already reported it, and the bug is still "open" (at time of writing). https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94713

Answer (score 23):

use

> defaults write com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench
>   NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool yes

to exclude workbench from dark mode

use

> defaults delete com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench
>   NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance

to reset to default

Comment: Agreed. Way better than switching the OS theme every time you want to use Workbench!

Comment: I'm getting this message :
`Domain (com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench) not found.`

`Defaults have not been changed.`

Comment: @ Szekelygobe , run osascript -e 'id of app "App Name"'  to get your <MySQLWorkbench bundle id>, then run the defaults write <your MySQLWorkbench Bundle-Identifier> NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool yes

Answer (score 5):

```
defaults write com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool yes
```

Run this in CMD

Ref: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92902

Comment: Solved my problem, disable the dark theme in MySQLWorkbench 

Answer (score 0):

Just run `curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/AmreeshTyagi/29220b3d55c21cf3664efa7352c0ee6e/raw/36a81e1ebc5e13b3543fecc0893285b2c6244276/workbench-ui-fix.sh`

OR

execute this gist https://gist.github.com/AmreeshTyagi/29220b3d55c21cf3664efa7352c0ee6e

Ref: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92902

Though all above answers are similar, but still sharing this handy script to fork.