# how can i style mySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

is there any way to style my mySQL Workbench? like :

1. change colors
2. channge fonts
3. etc..

thanks for the attention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Workbench Dark Theme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325408/mysql-workbench-dark-theme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a lot you can do, in terms of colors, but see the official documentation titled [Fonts and Colors Preferences](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-preferences-fonts-and-colors.html), and as user xAF commented on earlier, the StackOverflow question titled [MySQL Workbench Dark Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325408/mysql-workbench-dark-theme) also has suggestions.