# MySQL Workbench Dark Theme

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I just started taking courses on SQL and I've been trying out different GUI's. I like using MySQL Workbench but the white background kills my eyes. I've already searched and found a few other related posts talking about editing the xml file. I've tried editing it in several different ways but to no avail, I'm confused on specifically what I need to do. I'd appreciate it if someone could explain in simple steps, with examples, how to change the background color to something darker. Thank you!
Here is one of the threads I was trying to follow to change the xml file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325408/mysql-workbench-dark-theme

Comment: I tried from that link it only changes code editor window.Here is the screen shot of new background color with color scheme system default https://gyazo.com/3893f1017a461393d0b10de0ddd57e5f  and another screen shot with windows 7 theme https://gyazo.com/604da67dbf765a4be0d6aadf5177a7b1.

Comment: How exactly did you change that? What specific line and then what did you change it to?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot manually change most of the colors in MySQL Workbench. Depending on the platform you are on, it is possible to change the OS theme and the app will follow. On Windows + Linux you can use different themes, including light text on dark backgrounds. On macOS there was no theming so far and only recently (with Mojave) the dark mode became available to the masses. This mode is currently not supported, but will be in a next release.

Comment: that saved a lot of time, the "Standard" theme works well for MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 1):

Use notepad++ editor.Replace everything between these tags in code_editor.xml with gaston's xml tags

```
   <language name="SCLEX_MYSQL"> 
     ----
     ----
     -----
     <keywords name="User Keywords 3">
        <!-- Like user 2 but those that can appear between two expressions. --> 
        all and any as between escape false in is like or regexp sounds true unknown xor </keywords>
             .  
             .   paste new code between these tags
             .
      </language>
  <language name="SCLEX_MYSQL_50">
```

Restart Workbench and change theme to Window 7 or test all themes that works for you.You can try different colors using hex code for  background color with the tag that has comments "STYLE_DEFAULT THIS IS THE ONE FOR THE BACKGROUND!!!!!"

P.S: All credit goes to Gaston https://stackoverflow.com/users/5236061/gaston-martinez
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325408/mysql-workbench-dark-theme

Comment: This is not really producing a dark theme in Workbench. All you change with that approach are the code editor colors.

Comment: Read my first comment,provided screen shots and op still wants even though I warned it only changes only code editor window.