# Changing MySQL Workbench Editor to Dark Mode ( installed from Ubuntu Software )

Tags: mysql-workbench, darkmode

I have found many questions here answer this same topic, such as in:
[MySQL Workbench Dark Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157203/mysql-workbench-dark-theme) and
[MySQL Workbench Dark Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325408/mysql-workbench-dark-theme)

However they all work under the premise that my SQL Workbench folder has said *code_editor.xml* or even a data folder to begin with. I'm not that surprised since I wasn't able to install it with the .deb since it kept insisting it lacked dependencies, so I found it in the Ubuntu Software and got it from there. However, there are no such folders or files like in those answers. For one, its directory seems to be:

*usr/snap/mysql-workbench-community*

With a *which* command from my terminal I get this, however:

$~ *which mysql*

/usr/bin/mysql

$~ *which mysql-workbench*

mysql-workbench not found

$~ *which mysql-workbench-community*

/snap/bin/mysql-workbench-community

So yeah, it's not even named just " mysql-workbench " in the first place. And inside said folder I have three other folders: "9", "common" and "current". Using the Ubuntu search bar from there yields no results for either "data" folder or "code_editor.xml" file.

I have no idea how to proceed and am still pretty new to Ubuntu in general, so any help would be more than welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The file is located under
/snap/mysql-workbench-community/9/usr/share/mysql-workbench/data
but since is a snap package, is a read-only system, so is not possible overwrite that file.

I think you can't have a Mysql Workbench with dark theme in unbutu 2204, because there's no way to install the deb package.

I just installed another sql client, is a snap but has a dark theme, is called Antares.