# How can I change workbench 8.0 theme to dark using win10

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'd like to ask for a full tutorial to change my workbench 8.0 to dark mode the bright theme is killing my eyes, I had tried lots of workaround on StackOverflow but none of them work for me.
Do any of you have any method to change workbench to dark mode on windows10, please help my poor eyes out

Comment: the temporary workaround is using the magnifier built-in windows 10 , set the magnify rate to 100% in full-screen mode and invert the color of the whole screen.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325408/mysql-workbench-dark-theme for manual approaches. It doesn't seem to be supported by default in Win10 yet, even though the issue was closed here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70266

Comment: this method does not work on workbench8.0 at all

Comment: How about this user's modification of what I previously linked?: https://superuser.com/a/1477257/681623. Hope it helps as a temp solution until it correctly syncs with windows' theming (as they seem to suggest it should in the linked bug report).

Comment: this kind of work but in a very strange way, it changes the text background to black but not the editor's background

Answer (score 1):

### In Windows 10, September 2021

I've been looking for a solution to this, without success. As far as September 2021, and MySQL Workbench 8.0.26 build 972499 CE 64-Bits for W10, **it is NOT possible to enable any real dark theme/GUI option**. There's only pseudo solutions for this.

Let me list the few uncomplete-solutions I've found so far:

1. Change the query editor pan color scheme:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/32055190/7389293 This is sufficient
   answer for this point. I won't repeat the code. Again, this solution
   is only for the query editor, it DOES NOT affect the rest of the GUI.

| [image] |
| --- |
| *Ignore the errors in the query, please.* |

- NOTE: The code you have to change is located in `code_editor.xml` file
  at the folder of the MySQL Workbench's installation directory, usually
  at `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench x.x CE\data`
- There's additional options for this at: `Menu` → `Edit` → `Preferences` →
  `Modeling` → `Appearance`
- Remember to google for other different color schemes for adding to this file, and getting the style you desire. [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=theme%20mysql%20workbench%20github)

2. Change color scheme for the entire interface. Go to: `Menu` → `Edit` → `Preferences` → `Fonts & Colors` → `Color Scheme` drop-down list.

| [image: Description] |
| --- |
| *I think the W7 scheme is the darkest one.* |

I suggest you to use "Windows 7" or "High Contrast" options, which are darker than the others.

After making this changes, your GUI should look like in the first picture.

FINAL NOTE: A dark theme for MySQL WB seems to be on the works for W10. This answer should be obsolete in the future. → https://stackoverflow.com/a/54489701/7389293

Comment: I had apply windows7 theme on my workbench already, but I'v moved to dbforge for mySQL since it had a complete dark theme built in with other useful functions rather in workbench.

Answer (score -4):

MySQL Workbench follows the theme of the OS. If that is light then WB is light. If it's dark then WB uses that. Even high contrast is supported, if the OS is set to that.

In addition there's a file code_editor.xml that contains some color definitions, but those only affect syntax highlighting colors in SQL editors.

Comment: What you've said makes sense, but change to the dark theme doesn't work for me and neither of my other windows10 machine with a dark theme.

Comment: If MySQL Workbench (possibly after a restart once the color theme in the OS was changed) does not change the colors to follow that theme then something is wrong and may have found a bug. I haven't heard a long time about a problem in this area, but one never knows. In that case it makes more sense to file a bug report (https://bugs.mysql.com).

Comment: This bug had already been reported:https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90751

Comment: This answer in inaccurate. WB does not change with the OS theme (at least in W10).

Comment: Agree, it seems that that dark theme only take effect on non windows platform and it had already been optimized on macOS long before

Comment: Everything in this answer is correct, even today, 4 years after I wrote it. It's beyond me that it is downvoted. I personally wrote the theme handling in MySQL Workbench, so I know what's possible and what's not. But of course there can be bugs and changes in the OS that broke all or a part of that handling over time. But that doesn't affect the quality or correctness of my answer here!