# How to enable dark theme of MySql Workbench on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql

i'm new to Sql so please help me with it,I want to do this on **ubuntu**...thanks[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Workbench Dark Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325408/mysql-workbench-dark-theme)

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Please try googling previous questions before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32055190/7429535

Comment: I want to do the above in ubuntu.....