# How to disable dark theme for MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am looking for a way to manually disable the dark theme setting as it hurts my eyes while looking at the database tables. I couldn't find any settings in preferences. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command has been taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54254393/6543250). Still, mentioning the command here for future purposes.

To disable dark theme:
`defaults write com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool yes`

To enable dark theme again:
`defaults write com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool no`

Comment: I think you can mark your own answer as the correct answer. Thanks for posting this and I am shocked that the people at MySQL removed the preference for color in their app and forced everyone to dark mode. Like you, in dark mode, I couldn't read a thing.