# Change MySQL Workbench dark theme resultgrid color on macOS

Tags: macos, mysql-workbench

Is there a way to dim the result grid color? I find it too bright in the dark theme on macos and would like to have it gray or so (currently it looks very close to white).
I found a few tutorials how to change the colors for the app but apparently they refer to the query area only. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32055190/5268722)

[image]